# How to get address of an object in C#

Tags: c#

How can I get address of an object in c#?

i searched and found

```
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(obj, GCHandleType.WeakTrackResurrection);

int address = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(handle).ToInt32();
```

But need some more simple code

Is `&` operator can used here?

Comment: I know I'll regret asking, but why do you need the address of a C# object?

Comment: The real question is what do you plan to do with the address of an object in C# ?

Comment: Getting the address of an arbitrary object in .NET is not possible, but can be done if you change the source code and use mono.  See instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25410158/get-memory-address-of-net-object-c/25432952#25432952

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects by default don't have a fixed address in C#, you'll need to explicitly tell the garbage collector  to pin it.

See http://geekswithblogs.net/robp/archive/2008/08/13/speedy-c-part-3-understanding-memory-references-pinned-objects-and.aspx for a detailed description.

Answer (score 1):

Unsafe code.
Compile with /unsafe (checkbox in the VS project properties)

```
unsafe
{
    fixed(MyobjType* objptr = &myobj)
    {
      // do sthng
    }
}
```

Comment: This generates error like: Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('object')

Comment: @Peteter Only works with structs. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx